# How to install python-poppler-qt4 on windows

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, poppler

I would like to know how to install python-poppler-qt4 on windows.I have already installed python 2.7
,pyqt4 using window installer as well as SIP. However, when I tried to install python-poppler-qt4 through pip install, error was found :
  import PYQT4.pyqtconfig
ImportError:No module named pyqt.config

From what I have understand, it is because I installed the binary packages for pyqt4 rather than from the source packages so this pyqt.config.Yet if I installed it from source, it mean that I would have to make use of MSVC or MinGW 32 bits?

How do I resolve this problem? Thank you

Comment: you may refer the following link

    http://laconsigna.wordpress.com/2011/07/14/compiling-poppler-on-windows/