# Python poppler qt4 installation fails : Unsupported Qt version (5.6.2)

Tags: python, qt

Trying to install qt with

```
pip install python-poppler-qt4
```

in Windows 10. Got the following error.

```
(base) C:\Users\MachineSense>pip install python-poppler-qt4
Collecting python-poppler-qt4
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/72/20732d33836422ef07a7f0f86e452e2d236ab02626c71a66fb0302e3548e/python-poppler-qt4-0.24.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt4.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt4.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt4.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt4.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info\python_poppler_qt4.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    Unsupported Qt version (5.6.2). Try specifying the path to qmake manually via --qmake-bin=

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MACHIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-i350kmco\python-poppler-qt4\
```

Tried to get the qt version using the following command.

```
import inspect
from PyQt5 import Qt

vers = ['%s = %s' % (k,v) for k,v in vars(Qt).items() if k.lower().find('version') >= 0 and not inspect.isbuiltin(v)]
print('\n'.join(sorted(vers)))
```

Source : [How to find Version of Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23058718/how-to-find-version-of-qt/23097846#23097846)

Got the following output :

```
PYQT_VERSION = 330498
PYQT_VERSION_STR = 5.11.2
QOpenGLVersionProfile = <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QOpenGLVersionProfile'>
QOperatingSystemVersion = <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QOperatingSystemVersion'>
QT_VERSION = 330497
QT_VERSION_STR = 5.11.1
QVersionNumber = <class 'PyQt5.QtCore.QVersionNumber'>
```

So it appears that version is 5.11.2. But poppler is picking up version 5.6.2.

Any help on how to solve this.

Saw this post but is not of much help : [How to install python-poppler-qt4 on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287900/how-to-install-python-poppler-qt4-on-windows)

Comment: as for me `qt4` can means it is version for `PyQt4`, not `PyQt5`

Comment: I got it. I changed the command to pip install python-poppler-qt5.

Comment: But it is giving another error :  https://pastebin.com/SvFhdE2s